# How to store Base64-encoded image data in an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, base64, deployd

I make a post request and receive an array of image URLs. I need to then convert these images to base64 and save them as strings. Here is the code for converting the images (i used this reference: http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/):

```
 var convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas = function(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
};
```

Here is the function I call in the .then function after I receive the result from the $http post call:

```
 var base64Image = convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas(resultImages[i], function(base64Img){
      console.log(base64Img)
      dpd.studentanswers.post({
                    studentName: "Student" ,
                    answerImage: 'http://imagesource.com',
                    questionPrompt: image,
                    answerImageBase64: 'http://imagesource.com'
                    }, function(todo, err) {
                        if (err) {
                        alert(err.message || (err.errors && err.errors.title));
                        return;
                    }});
 });
```

It is not doing anything. It does not even log anything. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint? If nothing is being logged, then it would seem like your convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas callback is never being called, which means that your img.onload function is either never called or never reaches the callback.